# SUMIFS Excel function not working for me

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to get this function to work. I typed it as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(D1:D322,F1:F322,">="&B324,F1:F322,"<="&C324)
```

---

Putting in the direct date also gives me the same issue. I get a pop-up with the text; there is a problem with this formula.

Anyone have an idea?

### The results show on the right when I enter the function through the formula builder.

[image: View of excel sheet]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151583/discussion-on-question-by-sarah-ketel-sumifs-excel-function-not-working-for-me); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Hi, Did you check to see if the values in column F are actually dates, not text? If you highlight more than one of them Excel will give a sum in the bottom corner of the screen.

Comment: OP has actually resolved the issue, they had issues with the separators. They were using commas where as they required to use semicolons. The comments are moved to chat, one can refer to see.